# Convert string to mm/dd/yyyy datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert string which comes from textbox, for example in this format '03/24/2014' to DateTime. This is what I'm trying:

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");                    
dtAssemblyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", us);
```

or

```
dtAssemblyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

But no luck and I'm getting exceptions that the value cannot be casted as DateTime. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you mean `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Not clear, do you want to convert based on culture or based on a particular format. If ParseExact is failing, that's because the string isn't in that exact format...

Comment: Make sure you pass the right format to PArseExact, and don't put a cultureinfo, it's not required when you want your own format

Comment: Instead of a textbox, why not use a control specifically designed for DateTime, like a DateTimePicker?  Then you would have no need for any conversion because you would already have a DateTime!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is expressed in the format MM/dd/yyyy then

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");                    
dtAssemblyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy", us);
```

but I prefer to use DateTime.TryParse to avoid surprises...

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                     DateTimeStyles.None, 
                     out dtAssemblyDate))
    Console.WriteLine(dtAssemblyDate.ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`03/24/2014` isn't a valid date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format (there are only 12 months in a year<sup>1</sup>).

Either change your format string to `MM/dd/yyyy` or use a valid date in your chosen format.

<sup>1: Or 13 months in some types of [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but `"en-US"` uses the 12-month [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`03/24/2014` has the *day of the month* as the middle component. That might seem strange, but [that's how it's done in some parts of the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) (mostly Northern America).

Thus, when specifying the format for parsing, you also have to put the *day of the month* (`dd`) in the middle:

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");                    
dtAssemblyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy", us);
```

Obviously, it is not possible to parse a text field that accepts both middle-endian (`MM/dd/yyyy`) and small-endian (`dd/MM/yyyy`) dates, because ambiguities like `01/02/2014` cannot be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("24/03/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtOperationSignatureDate.Value, us.DateTimeFormat);
```

Whatever DateTimeFormat you require, you just need to pass corresponding culture with it.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

string date = textbox.Value;

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);